# How to populate an array before conditional render which is based on the length of the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to populate an array before render, and the render is conditional based on the length of the array.

If the length of the array > 0, do the render, otherwise don't.

But it seems that the length is always 0 becasue `useEffect` is asynchronous, so the render is never done.

Below is my code:

```
function OrderDetail(props) {
    const {userInfo} = useSelector(state => state.user)
    const [order, setOrder] = useState({});
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!userInfo){
            props.history.push("/")
            return
        }

        const fetchOrderAndItems = async () => {
            // Get an order from backend.
            const order = await axios.get("/api/orders/" + props.match.params.id, {
                headers:{
                    authorization: "Bearer " + userInfo.token
                }
            });
            const order_data = order.data
            setOrder(order_data)

            // Take out the id of all items in the order, retrieve each product from backend, 
            //push them in "items_array" and set it in the "items" state.
            let items_array = [];
            order_data.orderItems.forEach( async (orderItem) => {
                const {data} = await axios.get("/api/products/" + orderItem.productId);
                items_array.push(data);
            })

            console.log("items_array.length: " + items_array.length);
            console.log(items_array);

            setItems(items_array);
        }

        fetchOrderAndItems();
    }, [userInfo]);

    // For each item in the "items" state, return a <tr> element.
    const itemsHtml = items.map(item => {
        return <tr key={item._id}>
             Something to display.
            </tr>
    })

    // if itemsHtml.length  > 0, render {itemsHtml}, otherwise display "Your cart is empty.".
    // But what is displayed is always "Your cart is empty."
    return <table className="table text-center">
    <thead style={{border: "none"}}>
    <tr>
        <th style={{border: "none"}} scope="col"></th>
        <th style={{border: "none"}} scope="col">Name</th>
        <th style={{border: "none"}} scope="col">Price</th>
        <th style={{border: "none"}} scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th style={{border: "none"}} scope="col">Subtotal</th>
        <th style={{border: "none"}} scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {
        itemsHtml.length > 0?
            <tbody>
                {itemsHtml}
            </tbody>
            :
            <tbody>
            <tr className="text-center">
                <th className="text-center" scope="row" colSpan="6">Your cart is empty. </th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

The output of the 2 lines of "console.log" is:
[image]

We can see that the length of `items_array` is 0 while there is content in it, and I think it is because it is asynchronous.

And I guess because the length is 0, so the conditional render of `itemsHtml.length > 0?` is never true, so the desired content is never rendered.

Could anyone teach me how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried to understand your async logic, but you have a more fundamental problem: `itemsHtml > 0` should be `itemsHtml.length > 0`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sry it is a mistake, I have corrected it. But the problem in this post is not because of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of for-each'ing over the items you should map the item ids to an array of GET requests and `Promise.all` them. The `forEach` doesn't wait for the callbacks to complete, this is why the array is empty when you log it but become populated by the time the log is displayed.

`Promise.all` will wait for all mapped requests to resolve before it resolves with an array of resolved item values.

```
Promise.all(
  order_data.orderItems.map(
    ({ productId }) => axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`)
  ))
  .then(results => setItems(results));
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! But I think there should be an `await` before `axios`? Please revise that then I will accept your answer~

Comment: @powerseed It's an implicit promise return, no need to await it, `Promise.all` will do that. Updated answer with this bit of clarification.